# Sikuli Can't Click Image and Ask to Run the SikuliX Stuff as Admin

Tags: java, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I'm trying to click on image using java, but no success. 
I have this message in Console:

```
[log] App.focus:  [8364:BIStudio.exe]
[log] CLICK on L(228,136)@S(0)[0,0 1920x1080]
[error] RobotDesktop: checkMousePosition: should be L(228,136)@S(0)[0,0 1920x1080]
but after move is L(-1099,728)@S(1)[-1366,306 1366x768]
Possible cause in case you did not touch the mouse while script was running:
 Mouse actions are blocked generally or by the frontmost application.
You might try to run the SikuliX stuff as admin.
```

What should i do here? I tried using the IDE and worked after running as Admin.

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/295379

Comment: So if that worked for you as admin, what's the problem?

Comment: @EugeneS It was about running using java code. 
Had no permission to run the commands as admin.